# There seems to be a problem with my coc.vim

Tags: python, neovim

When I execute the following command

```
nvim hello.cpp
```

Enter insertion mode

The following error occurs when starting coding

```
Error detected while processing InsertCharPre Autocommands for "*"..script /home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line    7:
E319: No "python3" provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider"
```

I have tried many solutions

For example, executing`python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim` to improve my environment

But when I finish executing `:checkhealth` , this is the result

```
Python 3 provider (optional)
- Using:g:python3_host_prog ="/usr/local/python3.6/bin/python3"
- WARNING No Python executable found that can `import neovim`.Using the first available executable for diagnostics. 
- Executable: Not found
```

Next, I will try to modify the coc-stettings.json file

Add Code Snippet`"snippets.ultisnips.enable": false`

Completely ineffective

my neovim version
`NVIM v0.10.0-dev-695+g58f948614`

my ubuntu version is 18.04

Now I'm completely at a loss and don't know what to do